# OnlyOneReturn without DD anomaly

Tags: java, pmd

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/product/baselist", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<Object> baseListProductFilters(@RequestBody final ObjectNode json) {
    LOGGER.debug("Gettig all product filters");
    try {
        final int offset = json.get("offset") == null ? OFFSET_AUTOCOMPL
                : json.get("offset").asInt(OFFSET_AUTOCOMPL);
        final int limit = json.get("limit") == null ? LIMIT_AUTOCOMPL : json.get("limit").asInt(LIMIT_AUTOCOMPL);

        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK)
                .body(filterService.getList(getUsername(), ResourceType.PRODUCT, offset, limit));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOGGER.error("Error getting product filter list: ", e);
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).body(e);
    }
}
```

So here is my code. I have PMD code analyser installed. It suggests me that there should be ONLY ONE RETURN. So I did this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/product/baselist", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<Object> baseListProductFilters(@RequestBody final ObjectNode json) {
    LOGGER.debug("Gettig all product filters");
    ResponseEntity<Object> toReturn;
    try {
        final int offset = json.get("offset") == null ? OFFSET_AUTOCOMPL
                : json.get("offset").asInt(OFFSET_AUTOCOMPL);
        final int limit = json.get("limit") == null ? LIMIT_AUTOCOMPL : json.get("limit").asInt(LIMIT_AUTOCOMPL);

        toReturn = ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK)
                .body(filterService.getList(getUsername(), ResourceType.PRODUCT, offset, limit));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOGGER.error("Error getting product filter list: ", e);
        toReturn = ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).body(e);
    }
    return toReturn;
}
```

There is no more OnlyOneReturn violation but 'DD'-anomaly appears. My client requires OnlyOneReturn not to be ignored. Any ideas how can I solve this issue?

Comment: Please consider adding `pmd` tag, and removing `spring*` tags, since the question is not spring relevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My two cents as a PMD maintainer.

Rules in the controversial ruleset should be taken judiciously. Make sure it actually makes sense to add each. Including the whole ruleset just because it's part of PMD is generally a bad idea. We are working towards building better defaults / have better rules, but in the meantime just be careful.

DataflowAnomalyAnalysis is a poor rule as it currently stands.

- Not all anomalies mean there is an issue / makes sense. UR anomalies mean the code does not even compile. DU anomalies are actually common in code. DD anomalies may at best point to spurious assignments, but don't necessarily mean there is a bug either.
- The rule doesn't properly handle all Java constructs. `assert` is not handled, `for-each` is not handled, `try-with-resources` is not handled properly... There are plenty of [open issues on GitHub for this](https://github.com/pmd/pmd/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+label%3Ain%3Adata-flow)

We do plan to revamp it eventually (but is not a top priority at the moment, since we are working on some other core functionality that we believe have a much greater impact on everyday developer work).

In the meantime, you should probably either disable the rule, or [add suppressions](https://pmd.github.io/pmd-5.7.0/usage/suppressing.html) as needed.

Please, submit issues if you find more failing scenarios.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to use [`ExceptionHandler`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-ann-exceptionhandler) to handle error case in your controller. That way DD anomaly will go away.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is: What issue/who cares?

I think very few pieces of code could exist regarding *both* rules, that's why both ("OnlyOneReturn" as the "DataflowAnomalyAnalysis") are part of the [Controversial Ruleset](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/pmd-4.3.0/rules/controversial.html) ..stating:

> The Controversial Ruleset contains rules that, for whatever reason, are considered controversial. They are separated out here to allow people to include as they see fit via custom rulesets. This ruleset was initially created in response to discussions over UnnecessaryConstructorRule which Tom likes but most people really dislike :-)

So in this case you would have to decide, which rule you consider more important/applicable. (I usually stick to "OnlyOneReturn";)